# JPA - How to map the relationship between two tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to JPA, and trying to figure out how to correctly map the following relationship between two database tables:

`movies { id, title, rating }`

`ratings { id, rating }`

So that querying the movies database will return the rating string ('g', 'pg', etc) from the second table for that movie.  Each of these is their own @Entity and java class as shown below.    Do I have to something in the `getRating()` method of the `MovieCatalogEntity` to get the correct rating?

```
    @Entity(name="movieCatalog")
    public class MovieCatalogEntity {

        @Id
        @Column(name="ID", nullable=false)
        private long id;

        @Column(name="Title", nullable=false)
        private String title;

            ??? What goes here ????????
            private RatingEntity rating;
    }


@Entity(name="Rating")
public class RatingEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable=false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="Rating", nullable=false)
    private String rating;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See `@OneToOne`, `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn` annotations

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it assuming that a the same rating can appear on many Movies.

```
 @ManyToOne(optional=false) 
 @JoinColumn(name="rating_id", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable=false)
 public RatingEntity rating
```

Details of the @ManyToOne are found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking @ManyToOne was Entity to Entity, not table to table.

Comment: @RobertYetman Glad it helped. Please accept or upvote the answer if it did solve your problem. :)